# Disable Keyboard input in textbox , C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I have got a virtual Keyboard and I wanna fill textbox only with that applet and not with keyboard.
how can I restrict textbox to don't get filled by keyboard?

Comment: That sounds like a very bad idea from a UX perspective, since it most definitely will annoy users, since they have to use a virtual keyboard instead of the one they are actually used to. 
What is your reason for wanting to limit the user like this?

Comment: good day sir. its about security. i want to disable any keyboard input on my app, just virtual keyboard which i was developed can fill a textbox. have u suggested me how to solved problem like that.?

Answer (score 1):

You could solve that problem by handling the textbox-KeyPressed event.

If you use the following code every KeyPress gets ignored by the TextBox.

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

I hope that this helps you but I wouldnt recommend using it for the reasons Malte R. mentioned before.